# How can I use something like an array or list in Ant?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a list of strings (e.g. "piyush,kumar") in an Ant script for which I want to assign `piyush` to var1 like `<var name="var1" value="piyush"/>` and `kumar` to var2 like `<var name="var2" value="kumar"/>`.

So far, I'm using a buildfile like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="cutter" default="cutter">
<target name="cutter">
<for list="piyush,kumar" param="letter">
  <sequential>
    <echo>var1 @{letter}</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>
</target>
</project>
```

I'm not sure how to progress this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example using an ant-contrib [variable](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) and the [`math` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/math_task.html):

```
<var name="index" value="1"/>
<for list="piyush,kumar" param="letter">
  <sequential>
    <property name="var${index}" value="@{letter}" />
    <math result="index" operand1="${index}" operation="+" operand2="1" datatype="int" />
  </sequential>
</for>

<echoproperties prefix="var" />
```

Output:

```
[echoproperties] var1=piyush
[echoproperties] var2=kumar
```

This is all very un-Ant like though - once you've set these what are you going to do with them?

You might consider using an Ant [`script` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) instead for this sort of non-declarative processing.

Comment: i m using this in deploymentfile(ant script) for cutting two string in perl file and pushing them in one array then taking that array in deploymentfile(ant script) and cutting those two in Patch name and Deployment machine  variable then using these two variable to throughout the ant script so that now no need to declare them in input.properties file.

Comment: here we are taking `var` as suffix and we are incrementing the value `1,2...`like. can we change whole thing like first time `patch.name as variable`,second time `deployment.machine as variable`,.....
anyway in my script i m changing var1 and var2 to as per my requirement latter in script, but i just want to know can we do like this.

Comment: Docs for relevant tasks of 'for', 'foreach', 'PropertySelector':  http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/