# Ant Reading multiple list from Properties in one for loop

Tags: list, for-loop, ant, properties, ant-contrib

I have properties file that contains two list.

```
listA=A1,A2,A3
listB=B1,B2,B3
```

In my build file I am trying to get the value from both list at the same time, meaning if I am getting 2nd value from listA and then I should get the 2nd value from listB.  I couldn't find anything like index in ant. My for loop looks like below it works but for loop run 6 times.

```
<for list="${listA},${listB}" param="temp">
        <sequential>
            <echo>temp ${temp}</echo>
        </sequential>
</for>

Output :

temp A1
temp A2
temp A3
temp B1
temp B2
temp B3
```

Is there any way to read both list at the same time and get values in two different variables

Ideally I am trying to achieve is something like below

```
<for list="${listA},${listB}" param="tempa,tempb">
    <sequential>
        <echo>tempa ${tempa} , tempb ${tempb}</echo>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

which should return following Output :

```
temp A1 , temp B1
temp A2 , temp B2
temp A3 , temp B3
```

Comment: Take a look at [How can I use something like an array or list in Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308517/how-can-i-use-something-like-an-array-or-list-in-ant). You can adapt the solution to that question with logic that creates a property if `index` equals `2`.

Comment: I looked at the solution before posting the question and I am not sure if I totally understand what you are suggesting but ideally what I want is something like below.  Loop should only run three times and each time inside the loop I should be able to use the value from both list. 

Output :

temp A1  temp B1
temp A2  temp B2 
temp A3  temp B3